# Numerical integration scheme for stochastic system driven by colored noise (filtered white noise)

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, noise

I have given quite a few hours to this problem, but I seem to be getting nowhere. Can anyone just give a hint or point towards a text on where to go looking for the concept and solution.

[image]